# Loading apache server logs to HDFS using Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, camus

I want to load apache server logs to hdfs using Kafka.
**creating topic:**

```
./kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper 10.25.3.207:2181 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1 --topic lognew
```

**tailing the apache access log directory:**

```
tail -f  /var/log/httpd/access_log |./kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list 10.25.3.207:6667 --topic lognew
```

**At another terminal (of kafka bin) start consumer:**

```
./kafka-console-consumer.sh --zookeeper 10.25.3.207:2181 --topic lognew --from-beginning
```

**camus.properties file is configured as :**

```
# Needed Camus properties, more cleanup to come  
# final top-level data output directory, sub-directory will be dynamically      created for each topic pulled
etl.destination.path=/user/root/topics
# HDFS location where you want to keep execution files, i.e. offsets, error logs, and count files
etl.execution.base.path=/user/root/exec
# where completed Camus job output directories are kept, usually a sub-dir in the base.path
etl.execution.history.path=/user/root/camus/exec/history

# Kafka-0.8 handles all zookeeper calls
#zookeeper.hosts=
#zookeeper.broker.topics=/brokers/topics
#zookeeper.broker.nodes=/brokers/ids

# Concrete implementation of the Encoder class to use (used by Kafka Audit, and thus optional for now)    `camus.message.encoder.class=com.linkedin.camus.etl.kafka.coders.DummyKafkaMessageEncoder`

# Concrete implementation of the Decoder class to use
  #camus.message.decoder.class=com.linkedin.camus.etl.kafka.coders.LatestSchemaKafkaAvroMessageDecoder

# Used by avro-based Decoders to use as their Schema Registry
 #kafka.message.coder.schema.registry.class=com.linkedin.camus.example.schemaregistry.DummySchemaRegistry

# Used by the committer to arrange .avro files into a partitioned scheme. This will be the default partitioner for all
# topic that do not have a partitioner specified
    #etl.partitioner.class=com.linkedin.camus.etl.kafka.coders.DefaultPartitioner

# Partitioners can also be set on a per-topic basis
#etl.partitioner.class.<topic-name>=com.your.custom.CustomPartitioner

# all files in this dir will be added to the distributed cache and placed on the classpath for hadoop tasks
# hdfs.default.classpath.dir=

# max hadoop tasks to use, each task can pull multiple topic partitions
mapred.map.tasks=30
# max historical time that will be pulled from each partition based on event timestamp
kafka.max.pull.hrs=1
# events with a timestamp older than this will be discarded.
kafka.max.historical.days=3
# Max minutes for each mapper to pull messages (-1 means no limit)
kafka.max.pull.minutes.per.task=-1

# if whitelist has values, only whitelisted topic are pulled.  nothing on the blacklist is pulled
#kafka.blacklist.topics=
kafka.whitelist.topics=lognew
log4j.configuration=true

# Name of the client as seen by kafka
kafka.client.name=camus
# Fetch Request Parameters
#kafka.fetch.buffer.size=
#kafka.fetch.request.correlationid=
#kafka.fetch.request.max.wait=
#kafka.fetch.request.min.bytes=
# Connection parameters.
kafka.brokers=10.25.3.207:6667
#kafka.timeout.value=


#Stops the mapper from getting inundated with Decoder exceptions for the same topic
#Default value is set to 10
max.decoder.exceptions.to.print=5

#Controls the submitting of counts to Kafka
#Default value set to true
post.tracking.counts.to.kafka=true
monitoring.event.class=class.that.generates.record.to.submit.counts.to.kafka

# everything below this point can be ignored for the time being, will provide   more documentation down the road
##########################
etl.run.tracking.post=false
#kafka.monitor.tier=
#etl.counts.path=
kafka.monitor.time.granularity=10

etl.hourly=hourly
etl.daily=daily
etl.ignore.schema.errors=false

# configure output compression for deflate or snappy. Defaults to deflate
etl.output.codec=deflate
etl.deflate.level=6
#etl.output.codec=snappy

etl.default.timezone=America/Los_Angeles
etl.output.file.time.partition.mins=60
etl.keep.count.files=false
etl.execution.history.max.of.quota=.8

mapred.output.compress=true
mapred.map.max.attempts=1

kafka.client.buffer.size=20971520
kafka.client.so.timeout=60000

#zookeeper.session.timeout=
#zookeeper.connection.timeout=
```

I get errors when i execute the below command:

```
hadoop jar camus-example-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar com.linkedin.camus.etl.kafka.CamusJob -P camus.properties
```

Below is the error:

```
[CamusJob] - Fetching metadata from broker 10.25.3.207:6667 with client id camus for 0 topic(s) []
[CamusJob] - failed to create decoder
com.linkedin.camus.coders.MessageDecoderException:     com.linkedin.camus.coders.MessageDecoderException:     java.lang.NullPointerException
    at     com.linkedin.camus.etl.kafka.coders.MessageDecoderFactory.createMessageDecoder(MessageDecoderFactory.java:28)
    at com.linkedin.camus.etl.kafka.mapred.EtlInputFormat.createMessageDecoder(EtlInputFormat.java:390)
    at com.linkedin.camus.etl.kafka.mapred.EtlInputFormat.getSplits(EtlInputFormat.java:264)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.writeNewSplits(JobSubmitter.java:301)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.writeSplits(JobSubmitter.java:318)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.submitJobInternal(JobSubmitter.java:196)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1290)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1287)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1287)
    at com.linkedin.camus.etl.kafka.CamusJob.run(CamusJob.java:280)
    at com.linkedin.camus.etl.kafka.CamusJob.run(CamusJob.java:608)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:84)
    at com.linkedin.camus.etl.kafka.CamusJob.main(CamusJob.java:572)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
Caused by: com.linkedin.camus.coders.MessageDecoderException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.linkedin.camus.etl.kafka.coders.KafkaAvroMessageDecoder.init(KafkaAvroMessageDecoder.java:40)
    at com.linkedin.camus.etl.kafka.coders.MessageDecoderFactory.createMessageDecoder(MessageDecoderFactory.java:24)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:195)
    at     com.linkedin.camus.etl.kafka.coders.KafkaAvroMessageDecoder.init(KafkaAvroMessageDecoder.java:31)
    ... 23 more
[CamusJob] - Discarding topic (Decoder generation failed) : avrotopic
[CamusJob] - failed to create decoder
```

Please, suggest what can be done to resolve this problem.
Thanks in advance

Deepthy

Answer (score 0):

I've never used Camus. But I believe this is a Kafka related error and it has to do with how you're encoding/decoding the message. I believe the important lines in your stack trace are

```
Caused by: com.linkedin.camus.coders.MessageDecoderException: java.lang.NullPointerException
  at com.linkedin.camus.etl.kafka.coders.KafkaAvroMessageDecoder.init(KafkaAvroMessageDecoder.java:40)
  at com.linkedin.camus.etl.kafka.coders.MessageDecoderFactory.createMessageDecoder(MessageDecoderFactory.java:24)
```

How are you telling Kafka to use your Avro encoding? You've commented out the following line in your config,

```
#kafka.message.coder.schema.registry.class=com.linkedin.camus.example.schemaregistry.DummySchemaRegistry
```

So are you setting that somewhere else in code? If you're not, I would suggest uncommenting out that config value and setting it to whatever avro class you're trying to decode/encode in.

It might take you some debugging to use the right classpath and such, but I believe this is an easily solvable problem.

**EDIT**
In responding to your comments, I have a couple comments of my own.

1. **I have never used Camus.** So debugging the errors you get from Camus is not something that I'll be able to do very well or at all. So you'll have to spend some time (*maybe several hours*) researching and trying different things to get it to work.
2. I doubt [DummySchemaRegistry](https://github.com/linkedin/camus/blob/master/camus-example/src/main/java/com/linkedin/camus/example/schemaregistry/DummySchemaRegistry.java) is the correct configuration value that you need. Anything starting with Dummy is probably not a valid configuration option.
3. Doing a simple google search about camus and schema registry revealed some interesting links, [SchemaRegistry Classes](https://github.com/linkedin/camus/tree/master/camus-schema-registry/src/main/java/com/linkedin/camus/schemaregistry), [KafkaAvroMessageEncoder](https://github.com/linkedin/camus/blob/master/camus-kafka-coders/src/main/java/com/linkedin/camus/etl/kafka/coders/KafkaAvroMessageEncoder.java). Those are more likely to be the correct config values that you need. Just my guess, because again, I've never used Camus.
4. [This](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/camus_etl/RzSHsDzOdow) could also be of some use to you. I don't know if you've seen it. But if you haven't, I'm pretty sure googling the specific error you get is probably something you should before coming to Stack overflow.

Comment: I uncommented the config value  `kafka.message.coder.schema.registry.class=com.linkedin.camus.example.schemaregistry.DummySchemaRegistry`  but getting another error:

Comment: `com.linkedin.camus.coders.MessageDecoderException: java.lang.InstantiationException: com.linkedin.camus.example.schemaregistry.DummySchemaRegistry
        at com.linkedin.camus.etl.kafka.coders.MessageDecoderFactory.createMessageDecoder(MessageDecoderFactory.java:28)
        at com.linkedin.camus.etl.kafka.mapred.EtlInputFormat.createMessageDecoder(EtlInputFormat.java:390)
        at com.linkedin.camus.etl.kafka.mapred.EtlInputFormat.getSplits(EtlInputFormat.java:264)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.writeNewSplits(JobSubmitter.java:301)`